# Write Pandas Dataframe in parquet format for one record per id in dataframe and save it to S3 bucket is very slow using Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, azure, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read data from a SQL database table/view into a pyspark Dataframe and then want to write the data in a S3 bucket one file per id from the dataframe. At the moment, i have 50k id's which need to be written to an S3 bucket. The process to write is extremely slow and takes more than 2 hours to complete. I'm using Azure Databricks notebook to achieve this:

Following is a snippet of my code:

```
# Enable Arrow-based columnar data 
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")

df_from_query = spark.read \
               .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
               .option("url", url) \
               .option("dbtable", table_name) \
               .option("schemaCheckEnabled", False) \
               .option("accessToken", accesstoken) \
               .option("encrypt", "true") \
               .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
               .load()

df_from_query.cache()

#Converting to pandas df
pd_df_to_s3 = df_from_query.toPandas()

#Using the loop and output it to S3
filesCreated=0
for i, x in pd_df_to_s3.groupby(id):
     p = "/dbfs/mnt/{targetMountName}/{}.parquet".format(i, sourceName=sourceName, targetMountName=targetMountName)
     x.to_parquet(p, index=False)
     filesCreated = filesCreated + 1

print('NUmber of files created',filesCreated)
```

If i save the Dataframe into one parquet file then the query completes within seconds. But, the requirement is to store one file per id in the dataframe. that's where it becomes very slow.

Also, tried using Arrow but it hasn't helped a lot.

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated. Cheers
(I have mounted S3 bucket but haven't shared the code. Just wanted to keep the code for the troublesome part. Happy to share other parts if needed.)

Comment: I'm guessing your SQL is in Azure, because you are using Azure Databricks.  If your SQL is not in Azure, then it makes more sense to use Amazon Databricks so the data doesn't have to travel.

Comment: I know nothing about Apache Arrow.  Arrow's claim about data locality causes me to question whether it plays well with distributed computing.

Comment: So lets take a look at the throughput and see whether it makes sense. 50k records.  Say 2.5 hours.  50000  records / 150 minutes = 333 record/min or 5.55 record/second.
There is more to writing the file than writing the data.  Each separate file requires making a new connection all the overhead that involves.
let R = rows of data.
single file write = ( make_connection + (R * write_rate) ) vs
multi file write = ( R * (make_connection + write_rate) )
if you can benchmark writing a single row file, then we can see if this makes sense.  Maybe more nodes in cluster would help.